# Error al ejecutar $ npm start

Tags: reactjs

He buscado soluciones en la web pero no consigo encontrarlo. ¿Me pueden ayudar? Tengo una app en React y al ejecutar el comado npm start me aparece lo siguiente:

```
sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/marina/.npm/_logs/2021-11-30T10_32_21_555Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Te dice que no tienes node_modules, has hecho un npm install? Literalmente te está pidiendo hacerlo: *npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, **did you mean to install**?*

Comment: @Benito-B si lo hice, pero cada vez que abro el visual estudio code, me da el mismo error y tengo que hacer el npm install cada vez